# Javascript references to object

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to explain this question, so I'll illustrate with code.

```
var bob = {
    "1": ["a", "b"]
}

var jim = bob[1]

jim.shift()

print(bob[1])
```

Running this with d8, I get an output of `[b]`.

Notice how `bob` (the object I am referencing from jim) is being changed when I modify `jim`. I would like to have behavior where modifying `jim` does nothing to `bob`. That is, even after the `shift()`, I'd like `bob[1]` to still be `[a,b]` instead of `[b]`. I'm sure that this is a well-documented part of JS, but I wasn't sure how to search for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question in one form or another has come up a lot lately, for some reason.

Comment: Google's javascript engine through the shell (same thing as node)

Comment: Look for "JS pass by reference or value", "JS extending objects", etc...

Comment: @goodcow: `V8` is Google's JS engine.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: @chris: That seems to ask for a deep clone, and is about objects not specific to arrays.

Comment: @cookiemonster `d8` is the shell interface though

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it had a different name. Do you have doc reference for it?

Comment: @Bergi, I didn't see this question being specific to arrays either, just a coincidence that an array was used in the example.

Comment: @cookiemonster http://www.sandeepdatta.com/2011/10/using-v8-javascript-shell-d8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of bob[1]

```
var bob = {
    "1": ["a", "b"]
}

var jim = bob[1].slice(0)

jim.shift()

print(bob[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Object values in JavaScript are *references*, not complete objects-as-values.  When you assign `bob[1]` to `jim`, both `jim` and `bob[1]` reference the same object (the array).  Changing the array via one reference does not affect the other reference; they're both pointing to the same (changed) array.

Comment: How can I get the behavior that I want? Do I have to clone the object or something? Or is there a way to remove the reference?

Comment: Yes, cloning the object is a solution.

Comment: @goodcow yes, you'd have to clone the object yourself. For arrays, you could use `jim = bob[1].slice(0);` - be aware that cloning objects is, in general, a hard problem to solve. You're also better off *avoiding* copying objects when possible, since it's clearly not free (in terms of performance).

Comment: So generally, it's better to clone the fields of an object, not the object itself?

Comment: @goodcow well the problem is that it's got the potential to get really messy. In this case, it's simple, so there's no problem. For more complicated objects, however, what to copy and how to copy it can be hard to figure out; there's no good general-purpose always-works solution, in other words.